# How to design pattern in RTOS to manage these jobs?

Tags: design-patterns, workflow, rtos, mcu

There some jobs in an electronic-machine system, the micro-controller need to process these in sequence, and each job will taken some time (eg: motor run to some position)
jobs: A->B->C->D

Before, we use MCU like AVR, which only have one thread, we manage these jobs in a state-machine, the code pattern as follows:

```cpp
void flow()
{
  if (checkCondition())
  {
     return;
  }
  switch(state)
  {
    case A:
       actionA();
       state = B;
       break;
    case B:
       actionB();
       state = C;
       break;
    ...
  }
}
```

In this pattern, the function `flow()` is called in a loop, once the state changed, some waiting condition flags will be set, then these flags will be checked in the checkCondition().

Disadvantage of this pattern: When there are too many jobs, the code will be splited into pieces by the "case".

Now, we plan to reconstitute the software based on STM32+RTOS, and we think the previous pattern might not be the best practice in multi-thread.

What's the best practice to manage these jobs in multi-thread system?

Answer (score 0):

Use of a [FIFO (First In, First Out)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) register or queue would be the preferred design pattern here.

At a high level:

1. The job comes in and is placed at the back of the queue (enqueue). Additional jobs can be added to the back of the queue in quick succession without issue.
2. The job at the front of the queue is processed. The time the job takes to process is inconsequential.
3. When the job at the front of the queue is finished, it sends a signal to the queue to remove it (from the front) of the queue (dequeue)
4. If the queue is not empty, then repeat the process (from step 2).